# how to add a stored column of type jsonb

Tags: sql, cockroachdb

I am using the below query

ALTER TABLE t ADD COLUMN c jsonb AS (jsonb_build_object(d->'e')||jsonb_build_object(d->'s')) STORED;

but i am getting the folllowing error?

ERROR:  jsonb_build_object(): context-dependent operators are not allowed in computed column

ERROR:  jsonb_build_object(): context-dependent operators are not allowed in computed column

Answer (score 0):

welcome to the CockroachDB community!

1. If you want to "concatenate" two JSONB values (meaning putting key-value pairs from both JSONB values into one JSONB value), then you can do

```
CREATE TABLE t (i JSONB, j JSONB);
INSERT INTO t VALUES ('{"k1": 1}', '{"k2": 2}');
ALTER TABLE t ADD COLUMN k JSONB AS (i || j ) STORED;
```

```
SELECT * from t;
```

gives me

```
      i     |     j     |         k
------------+-----------+---------------------
  {"k1": 1} | {"k2": 2} | {"k1": 1, "k2": 2}
```

2. `d->'e'` and `d->'s'` will both be of JSONB type so I think in your particular case, you can do

```
ALTER TABLE t ADD COLUMN c jsonb AS ((d->'e')::JSONB || (d->'s')::JSONB) STORED;
```